# Keycloak CORS issue when being redirected to login

Tags: node.js, express, cors, keycloak

I am trying to get the [nodeJS keycloak adapter](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect) working with my Express application, but am facing a CORS issue when it tries to redirect to the login page for routes I have protected with the keycloak middleware:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://192.168.132.44:8080/auth/realms/Actora/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=actora-test&state=0e9c9778-c41b-4aa8-8052-d0f0125045ac&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fauth%2Fchecktoken%3Fauth_callback%3D1&scope=openid&response_type=code.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5001' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

In my keycloak client settings I have added a single value of '*' to the Web Origins config section.

I have also enabled cors on my node express application using the node cors library, following this express guide [here](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight)

```
var cors =  require('cors'),
  app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors()); //enable for all pre-flight requests
```

I using version 3.2.1 of keycloak in case that makes any difference (I see a new version is out as an RC)

Has anyone faced similar issues and managed to resolve? I have been digging through many JBOSS mailing list threads and other stackoverflows, and all seem to suggest its as simple as adding the '*' entry to the web origins config section for the client on the keycloak admin site but this is not the case for me.

Thanks

Comment: The `http://192.168.132.44:8080/auth/realms/Actora/protocol/openid-connect/auth` endpoint isn't served by your node application, right? It is instead served by your other server that's running the JBOSS stuff?

Comment: Correct, so does this mean some form CORS enabling is needed by the other server, the JBOSS one that our keycloak is running off?

Comment: No that should not be needed, could you give a bit more details on your NodeJS app, how do you serve the front end ? Or is a separate webapp ? Are you using bearer-only ?

Comment: Yes, you must CORS-enable the JBOSS server where your keycloak is running. (CORS enabling the node backend from which you are serving your frontend client code is not relevant, because that's not the server your frontend code is sending the cross-origin request to.)

Comment: Our node and web app live in the same project folder, our express app serves our web app (angularJS) from  a build directory. We are not using bearer-only, we are using credentials as the access type.

Comment: @SébastienBlanc - as you can see sideshowbarker says otherwise, which of you is correct?

Comment: Is your AngularJS app using the keycloak.js library ? Sorry to ask simple questions but I need as much details as I can.

Comment: No, we are only using the nodejs adapter for protecting the api end points in our express router. Although of course this still means you could get to webapp content without needing to be logged in, does this mean we should actually be using both the client side javascript adapter and the nodejs one?

Comment: If you just expose the endpoints APIs in NodeJS the good practice is : to have a separate keycloak client for the frontend and use the keycloak.js in your webapp, that will be do the redirect etc ... then you can call the nodejs endpoints from your angular app passing the auth token in the headers. Your NodeJS keycloak client will be another bearer-only client.

Comment: Umm ok, so I will need two clients setup in my realm, one for the front-end app and one for the express app?

Comment: Are there any good examples of this kind of setup you can refer me to please?

Comment: You can take a look here https://github.com/sebastienblanc/devoxxfr/tree/master/nodejs-service and here https://github.com/sebastienblanc/devoxxfr/tree/master/angular-client , you can also check our quickstarts https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts

Comment: @SébastienBlanc - thanks I am not sure we really need to have two clients setup, at this stage we only care about protecting the resources in our node express application. We just want to prove we can get the redirect flow working, obtain an access token after authorising a user, store this in our sessionDB (we are using express-session) and redirect back. See the answer just posted now, that's really what I want to focus on understanding and resolving right now.

Comment: @mindparse Did you resolve this?

Comment: @mindparse did you find the solution?

Comment: @tryingToLearn I was facing the same issue but it got resolved by replacing the secret as I missed some letters earlier

Comment: I think this problem is same as https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-13077 .

Answer (score 31):

Just put the url of your app like "http://localhost:8081" in "Web Origins" field of client settings in Keycloak.

Comment: Absolutely did it for me! THANK YOU :-)

Comment: I am hosting my keycloak on https://www.cloud-iam.com/. My backend is in Spring Boot and front end in Angular 12. On my local keycloak I just added the * for Web Origins. But on the cloud-iam keycloak I had to add the URL of my Spring Boot API service. It worked!! Thank you so much

Comment: Just got to love it when you try something on SO with 23 upvotes and it doesn't work. I have even added * wildcard to Web Origins and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 21):

I am also working on this issue with mindparse.

I think the key issue here is that the keycloak server is not responding with any ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN headers despite the fact that he has correctly configured the "web Origins" setting in the keycloak admin portal.

A more in depth flow of the process is:

1. The user attempts to call a keycloak secured route on a node express server
2. Keycloak middleware detects that the user is not authenticated and 
   responds to the request with a 302 (redirect) to a custom login page hosted 
   by the keycloak server.
3. The browser sends an OPTIONS request to the keycloak server to check if it is 
   because it is a cross origin request.
4. The keycloak servers response DOES NOT include the ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-
   ORIGIN header to tell the browser that it has permission to make this 
   request.
5. The browser then reads this response and therefore does not make the follow 
   up request because it did not pass the access control allow origin checks

Comment: Can you detail step 1 ? I suspect you do a XMLHttpRequest , that make no sense with a redirect. Redirect only make sense if the browser does it directly (not through an ajax call). See my previous comment on the OP for the good approach for this.

Comment: That is correct yes. We have an angular application that makes a call to check if a user is logged in when any angular state is navigated to. This means that when the user navigates to the website in the browser, it will immediately make this call to our checktoken method in our express server.

But from what you are saying it sounds like it is not possible to secure an api resource in the way/flow we are trying to? You HAVE to secure the client first and then use the token from the client to access to services?

Comment: I think I am running into same issue, what will be the correct flow to resolve this issue any idea?

Comment: @Balkrishna, I was facing the same issue but it got resolved by replacing the secret as I missed some letters earlier

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem. I am using Keycloak 6.0.1

In my case, I had to add  `"enable-cors": true` in `keycloak.json` in my Java backend server.

Afterward, I had another issue: `401 UNAUTHORIZED`.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53627747/11703367) solved the problem

Answer (score 6):

Web Origins must be set correctly for a configured client, yes, but it too has some pitfalls because a "+" setting depends on other values.

E.g., I had this **wrong** configuration for local tests:

```
Root URL: http://localhost:3000/
Valid redirect URIs: *
Web Origins: +
```

... and it failed with a CORS issue like you describe.

The issue lay with the other two settings, so this is **correct** and works now:

```
Root URL: http://localhost:3000
Valid redirect URIs: /*
Web Origins: +
```

(The KeyCloak UI is a usability nightmare on many fronts, imo, this is just one pitfall)

Comment: That did it for me, thank you. How incredibly non-obvious. I'm curious how you figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced CORS issues while trying to connect to KeyCloak, even though I had correctly filled out the "Web Origins" url.

Turned out I accidentally connected to the wrong App (Client) and tenant (Realm), therefore not passing the CORS checks. Pointing to the right app and tenant fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue in my case?
I tried a lot of "solutions" mentioned above. These didn't work for me.

I was running Keycloak on docker using the docker image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2, I stopped that container and created another one with the docker image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.5

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.5 start-dev
```

In this container, the web origins works like a charm!