# What is the best way to configure swagger with keycloak + wildfly?

Tags: swagger, wildfly, keycloak, swagger-ui

I have already configured Keycloak role based access control with my java API project and it is deployed with Wildfly and runs without any errors. Since I have tested and confirmed the responses with Postman, I needed to use Swagger in-order to generate API documensts.

Using Swagger Inspector I created an API definition and exported that via SwaggerHUB to use it in SwaggerUI which I run locally. With web-origins and all the necessary steps configured in Keycloak and with authentication parameters set in Swagger script, I get the below error..

*"
Access to fetch at (api request) from origin (swagger ui path) has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
"*

I have noticed that if I bypass Keycloak, this works. What might be the best solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: This issue was solved by doing what mentioned in following answer.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56967613/14489697)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycloak CORS issue when being redirected to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220566/keycloak-cors-issue-when-being-redirected-to-login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue referring this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56967613/14489697). I too added `"enable-cors": true`  in keycloak.json in my Java back-end server which was Wildfly and tested the same implementation in server environment successfully.